# Collect CakePHP 3 Shell Output and Errors

Tags: php, cakephp

I found a post that shows how to redirect the shell output and errors to files for CakePHP 2.x, any idea on how I can do so with CakePHP 3.x?

Here is the code snippet I found for CakePHP 2.x

```
public function __construct($stdout = null, $stderr = null, $stdin = null) {
    // This will cause all Shell outputs, eg. from $this->out(), to be written to
    // TMP.'shell.out'
    $stdout = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.out');

    // You can do the same for stderr too if you wish
    // $stderr = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.err');

    parent::__construct($stdout, $stderr, $stdin);
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Shell\ConsoleOutput' not found
```

Is ConsoleOutput in CakePHP 3.x and if so, what is the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use class below like:

```
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleOutput;

$output = new ConsoleOutput();
$io = new ConsoleIo($output);
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to be redirecting the output to a file though... any ideas why?

Comment: Ya, I tried that, its not working... I posted a new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620364/cakephp-3-redirect-consoleoutput-to-file