# CakePHP 3 Redirect ConsoleOutput to File

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to redirect the console output from a shell to a file in CakePHP 3

I found some snippets for CakePHP 2, however, they do not seem to be working...

Here is the code I have so far...

```
public $rootLogsDirectory = ROOT . DS . 'tmp' . DS . 'logs';
public $outputName;

public function __construct($stdout = null, $stderr = null, $stdin = null) {

    if(!is_dir($this->rootLogsDirectory)) {

        mkdir($this->rootLogsDirectory);
    }

    $this->outputName = tempnam($this->rootLogsDirectory, 'cronjobs');

    $stdout = new ConsoleOutput('file://' . $this->outputName . '.out');
    $stderr = new ConsoleOutput('file://' . $this->outputName . '.err');

    $ioNew = new ConsoleIo($stdout, $stderr);

    $ioNew->out('test');

    parent::__construct($ioNew);
}
```

However, `$this->out('hello world')` is not being written to the file...

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong use statement, I changed it from

```
use Cake\TestSuite\Stub\ConsoleOutput;
```

to

```
use Cake\Console\ConsoleOutput;
```